# Is it possible to capture all JS exceptions by running all the code try...catch block?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Why don't people write all their JS code inside one big try...catch block? Or even better, tart all your code in one function and initiate your program by calling that function form a try...catch block. Why isn't this the norm? What is the catch?

```
function allMyJSCode() {
    console.log("I can get here");

    foo.bar = ""; //accessing property of uninitialized object

    console.log("but never here");
}

try {
    allMyJSCode();
} catch(error) {
    console.log("Error from  allMyJSCode: " + error);
}
//I can get here
//Error from  allMyJSCode: ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Comment: Because the browser will show you the error in the console when an exception occurs, you don't need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Because once an error occurs, the rest of the code won't be executed, it will go directly to the `catch` block and ignore code that could be important. You don't want that.

Imagine this scenario:

```
// Important code #1

// Important code #2
```

Now, if you group these two together in one giant `try...catch` and for some reason `Important code #1` throws an error then `Important code #2` will never be executed and could cause problems, whereas if each of these where wrapped in their own `try...catch`, then no matter what happens in `Important code #1`, `Important code #2` will be reached and get executed.

`Important code #1` could be as trivial as changing the background of an element, and it could prevent the execution of code that handles populating data, sending requests, ...